# I would like to have some tasks running every day and others running every week

Tags: airflow

While assigning two different DAGs for different tasks its showing "Tried to set relationships between tasks in more than one DAG"

Comment: could you paste the logs and dag config?

Answer (score 1):

Task can not be assigned to more than one DAG.
You can however create a code that generate tasks from configuration file thus using the same configuration file to be used in daily DAG & weekly DAG.

Another option is to use one 1 daily dag that uses also [DayOfWeekSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b4770725a3aa03bd50a0a8c8e01db667bff93862/airflow/sensors/weekday.py#L25).
In that way you can execute your daily tasks as usual and have more tasks that will run only once a week.